# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using the Python MySQL connector to add data to a table by updating the row.  A user enters a serial number, and then the row with the serial number is added.  I keep getting a SQL syntax error and I can't figure out what it is.

```
  query = ("UPDATE `items` SET salesInfo = %s, shippingDate = %s, warrantyExpiration = %s, item = %s, WHERE serialNum = %s")
        cursor.execute(query, (info, shipDate, warranty, name, sn, ))
        conn.commit()
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE serialNum = '1B0000021A974726'' at line 1
```

"1B0000021A974726" is a serial number inputted by the user and it is already present in the table.

Comment: no `,` before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `,` before the `WHERE` statement